# Add Gallery image into Edit Text fields

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-image

In my app I used the below link,in this link they used emoticon like that I want to add initially put the Gallery images into the Edit Text fields how can I do this task.[This link followed the Gallery images how to use the emoticons](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon)